# Macbook Pro 7.1 Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: macbook-pro

Ive just installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my macbook pro 7.1. There are a few things that I cant get to work correctly.

The first is the temperature control. The fans don't seem to run at all and my Macbook pro gets really hot and sluggish.

Secondly is the sound, the sound doesn't seem as loud as it is under macosx, and the same as the brightness its really dim and I cant get it as bright, I think this is due to fact I cant find the nvidia driver that i had installed when I was running 10.04.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install the tools pointed out on [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro6-2/Maverick) website:

Answer (score 1):

For the sound run "alsamixer" in terminal and set front speaker to 100%. For the brightness problem you have to install the NVIDIA driver here: http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-285.05.09-driver.html. Keep in mind that after the driver is installed the brightness cannot be changed with Ubuntu and must be changed with the NVIDIA X Server Settings application. You probably have also noticed that 3d games don't work properly. To install the driver go to the Ubuntu software center and uninstall Nouveau. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> in my case) ad login. Type `sudo service lightdm stop`. Then install the driver with sudo sh. It will guide you through the installation. After the installation reboot.

Answer (score 0):

The ppa fixes many problems:

https://launchpad.net/~mactel-support/+archive/ppa

You can use `alsamixer` in the commandline to put up your volume.

The fans are controlled by macfanctld (you can find that in the ppa).